# Display empty taxonomy terms with get_terms()

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have a function setup as follows:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms("wpsc_product_category");
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <li class="calendar-filter-menu-item" data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->count; ?></li>
    <?php }
 } ?>
```

Which displays the taxonomy `slug` and `count` for each taxonomy, only problem is it's not showing a taxonomy that has no posts in, only taxonomies with posts assigned to them are being show, is it possible to show empty taxonomies as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the `hide_empty` [argument of `get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Possible_Arguments). It's default value is set to `true`.

Do it somewhat like this:

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$terms = get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string request mode, use "0" instead of "false" :

```
$terms = get_terms('hide_empty=0');
```